# In Buffer overflow exploitation what if JMP ESP address contains bad characters?

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I was writing an exploit for BOF. The server accepts only ASCII payloads. FInally I wnted to jump to my shellcode which is clearly in the stack. But only one module is available without ASLR and DEP which has address starting from 56566577. I got JUMP ESP, suppose in 5757578E, this doesn't work. Becuase the 0x8E outside the scope of ASCII 0x00 to 0x7F. Consider no other register has the shellcode. 
How can I deal with certain situations?

To create ASCII shellcode I use below:

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell_bind_tcp -a x86 -f perl --platform windows LHOST=192.168.1.1 LPORT=8181 -b "\x00" EXITFUNC=seh -e x86/alpha_upper
```

But this also has character above 0x7F. How can I generate shellcode within 0x00 - 0x7F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a different pivot, such as `call esp` or `pop eax; call eax;` maybe a blind `ret` will work. There are several other alternatives to `jmp esp`, you just have to find one that works for you.

If you control a value in any of the other registers you can usually find a gagdet that will call the registry at an offset f.ex: `call [eax+0x16];` and adjust the value in said register to point to `jmp esp` with the offset applied.

Comment: Thanks. I think push ESP; RET also will work. I got the tricks.